# Issues to make DataSet Public

Tags: vb.net

I'm familair with VBA/SQL programming in a excel environment. I'm recently started to get acquainted with vb.net but I'm strugling with a number of topics. One of these topics relates to public DataSet handling. Hope someone can help with this.

I defined a Module with the below VB code with the attempt to create a (public accesable) DataSet:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Public ds As DataSet

    Public Sub CRMds()

        Dim con As SqlConnection

        con = New SqlConnection("Server=MI5047LT\DELIMA01;Initial Catalog=CRM01;Integrated Security=SSPI")

        Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM CRM01Main"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        da.Fill(ds, "CRM01Main")

        con.Close()
        con = Nothing

    End Sub

End Module
```

Within the above module (code not show) I'm also verifying if the DataSet is correctly populated (returns a correct DataSet population).

When I'm Loading a Form(1) I'm calling this module with a verification step checking if DataSet is correctly populated:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    call Module1.........
    varXX = ds.Tables("CRM01Main").Rows(0)("Contact_ID").ToString

    MsgBox(varXX)

End Sub
```

("Contact_ID" is the SQL Column Name)

The error message appears when running this application:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

apperatly meaning no values are populated in this DataSet(?).

Note: When I run this procedure with a "single variable (e.g. Var="OK") this variable is visible in any form opened.

Main Objective is to populate a initial created DataSet (through Module1) over multiple forms.

I'm realize above query is most probably a very basic issue but unfortunately I'm strugling for a number of weeks to figure out the correct code or procedure. Any help would ne highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with anything being `Public` and everything to do with scope.  If you already have this:

```
Public ds As DataSet
```

then what is this for:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
```

If you had a rubbish bin outside your house and then you put a rubbish bin in your bedroom and threw some rubbish in it, would you expect that rubbish to magically appear in the rubbish bin outside?  I would expect not.

If you expect to get something from that `ds` member variable then you need to assign something to it, not to a different variable declared locally within a method that ceases to exist when that method completes.

You should do some reading on the difference between local variable and member variables (fields).

EDIT:

To be explicit, don't declare a new variable and assign to that but rather assign to the existing variable:

```
ds = New DataSet()
```

Comment: Works great now and indeed as expected very basic mistake I made! Recognize have to go to a learning curve but for now I can proceed. Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dim in vb.net is used to Dimension (Declare) a local variable. The compiler will look for the closest scope first for a variable. If the compiler finds a local variable it stops looking and that is the variable it uses.

If an Object has a .Dispose method, it should be called. For example, connections in ADO.net may have unmanaged code that needs to be cleaned up. Classes may be doing that clean up in the .Dispose method. Setting an object to Nothing does not accomplish this clean up in a timely manner. Using...End Using blocks were created to handle this for you. Notice that 3 ADO.net objects are in a single Using block separated by commas. The resource will be closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Public ds As DataSet

Public Sub CRMds()
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=MI5047LT\DELIMA01;Initial Catalog=CRM01;Integrated Security=SSPI"),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CRM01Main;", con),
        da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "CRM01Main")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great now and indeed as expected very basic mistake I made! Recognize have to go to a learning curve but for now I can proceed. Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Nicolaas If my answer solved your problem, please accept it clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Glad I could help.